# Change HTML TD background color dynamically based on value using PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table, background-color

I am trying to change the TD background color dinamically but it makes me crazy because I really don't know how to fix the code.

This is my code:

```
 <td data-column="% Over 0.5 SH" style="background-color: <?php echo $backgroundColorOver05SH; ?>">
<?php 
if (($row['TotalMatch']) > 9){ 
$percover05sh = $row['OK_05sh'] / $row['TotalMatch'] * 100; 
echo sprintf("%.2f", $percover05sh);


if ($percover05sh > 80){
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "green";
} elseif ($percover05sh >= 70 and $percover05sh <= 79.99  ){
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "yellow";
} else {
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "red";
}
```

I think I'm in the right direction, but I can't get the right solution.
Any suggestion please? Thanks!

**EDIT:** This code now it's working! This is my full code:

```
    <?php 
if (($row['TotalMatch']) > 9){ 
$percover05sh = $row['OK_05sh'] / $row['TotalMatch'] * 100; 

if ($percover05sh >= 80){
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "green";
} elseif ($percover05sh >= 70 && $percover05sh < 80  ){
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "yellow";
} else {
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "red";
}

}else{
echo 'No Bet';
}     ?>
<td data-column="% Over 0.5 SH" style="background-color: <?php echo $backgroundColorOver05SH;?>;">
<?php
echo sprintf("%.2f", $percover05sh);    
?>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring `$backgroundColorOver05SH` _before_ you use it in your `<td>`?

Comment: "_I really don't know how to fix the code_" What needs fixing? Does something not work?

Comment: @brombeer You're right,  but I tried to declare before but nothing works. Maybe I put it in the wrong place. Could you help me please? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what more I can say than: place your `<td ...` after your PHP code where you declare `$backgroundColorOver05SH`.

Comment: You should _calculate_ the value of `$percover05sh` before you output this TD (because you need it to determine the value for `$backgroundColorOver05SH`), but the part where you actually output its value to show it as _content_ of the table cell, of course still belongs _into_ it.

Comment: What would be the "right solution"? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first:

```php
 
<?php 
if (($row['TotalMatch']) > 9){ 
$percover05sh = $row['OK_05sh'] / $row['TotalMatch'] * 100; 
echo sprintf("%.2f", $percover05sh);


if ($percover05sh > 80){
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "green";
} elseif ($percover05sh >= 70 && $percover05sh < 80  ){
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "yellow";
} else {
    $backgroundColorOver05SH = "red";
}
?>
<td data-column="% Over 0.5 SH" style="background-color: <?=$backgroundColorOver05SH;?>;">
<?php
/* make sure to close:
if (($row['TotalMatch']) > 9){ 
*/
}
?>
```

If the color doesn't change maybe it is set by a different CSS rule or script?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried but I can't see the value (numbers) but the cells are colored without anything

Comment: Ok, from your code I fixed it, Between td tags I need to put "echo sprintf("%.2f", $percover05sh);" and it's working! I will edit my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from changing the order in your code (as written in the comments to the question), I would add a semicolon after the background-color value echoed by PHP in the style attribute, i.e.

```
<td data-column="% Over 0.5 SH" style="background-color: <?php echo $backgroundColorOver05SH; ?>;">
```

Comment: This could have been a comment